How do I get the unique item (remove duplicates) from column A and display pass if all values are pass from column B, otherwise it's a fail
How do I output the unique item (remove duplicates) from column A and output pass if all values are pass and fail if even one value is a fail or blank from column B:
Example:
Column A   Column B
jack             Pass
jack             Pass
jack             Pass
jack             Pass
don              Pass
don              Fail

So, column C and D should be:
Column C   Column D  
jack             Pass
don              Fail

I tried this to remove duplicates  =UNIQUE(A1:A6)
not sure how to combine another formula to display column C and D.

You've received three accurate answers which makes it a bit tough to identify just one that is "good". But please pay forward by accepting one of the these.

As I understand your question, these are the requirements you want to achieve:
Pass: The result is "Pass" only if all corresponding values in Column B are "Pass".
Fail: The result is "Fail" if there is at least one "Fail" or if any corresponding value in Column B is blank.
You can try this formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")), IF(COUNTIF(FILTER(A1:A, (B1:B="Fail")+(B1:B="")), UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>""))) > 0, "Fail", "Pass")}, COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>""))), 2))

Sample Output:

Reference:
CountIf
Array_Constrain
Filter

Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer

A very small issue, but the OP spells "Pass" and Fail" with leading Caps. There is something to be said for using lowercase to "detect" the Column B value, but then use leading caps for the answer.

you may try
={UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:A,1)),REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:A,1)),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,LET(t,UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=x)),IF(COUNTA(t)>1,"Fail",t)))))}



You may also try little bit simpler one, ={UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:A,1)),REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:A,1)),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,x,B:B,"Fail")>0,"Fail","Pass"))))}.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=query({A:A,switch(B:B,,"Fail",B:B)},"Select Col1,min(Col2) Where Col1!='' group by Col1 label min(Col2) ''")



Thanks a bunch to James Z (for cleaning my post), Harun24hr, Alma_Matters, and rockinfreakshow !  All solutions work great!   Much appreciated.

??? Why would this answer be down-voted; of all the answers (and they are all good) it is the least complicated, easiest to understand.
